# UIButton Text is cut off not according to the width, how to set width wrap content?

Tags: ios, swift

these several days im learning iOS Development, I have a problem where my text button is clipped to the wrong width,
[image]

how can I make the UIButton match the width of the content? below is my code

```
let btnPost = UIButton()
    btnPost.setTitle("POST", for: .normal)
    btnPost.backgroundColor = Color.shared.accent
    btnPost.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    btnPost.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    btnPost.layer.masksToBounds = true
    btnPost.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 15, bottom: 5, right: 15)
    btnPost.addTarget(
        self,
        action: #selector(baseDidTapPost(_:)),
        for: .touchUpInside)
    
    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnPost)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

Thanks

Comment: Delete the line about `btnPost.titleEdgeInsets`. Now try it. Is the result better?

Comment: Also try saying `btnPost.translatesAutoresizingMask = false`

Comment: not cropped, but I need the padding, how do I maintain the margins?

Comment: What do you mean "I need the padding"? I think I just proved to you that you yourself are the one removing the padding!

Comment: I need the padding between text and color background, when I delete btnPost.titleEdgeInsets, it's removing the padding

Comment: U want button show like P \n O \n S \n  T?

Comment: There's some answer in related question, maybe they can answer u.

Comment: But _that was not your question_. You did not ask how to provide some sort of padding. The title of your question is that the text is cut off. You asked why the button was cutting off the text, and I told you why! It was because you were telling it to do that. You stop telling it, it stops doing that. The end. If you wanted to know how to make a button larger than its text you should have asked that.

Comment: However, I'll give you an idea: remember these are _insets_. If you wanted the opposite of insets, maybe you should try the opposite of your numbers — negative numbers. Try it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to just remove the `btnPost.titleEdgeInsets` and add a `frame` to your button

```
btnPost = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 20))
```

complete code :

```
let btnPost = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 20))
btnPost.setTitle("POST", for: .normal)
btnPost.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
btnPost.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
btnPost.layer.cornerRadius = 10
btnPost.layer.masksToBounds = true
btnPost.addTarget(self,action: #selector(baseDidTapPost(_:)),for: .touchUpInside)
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnPost)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```